# Template with ACF and Pagebuilder

Tags: posts, advanced-custom-fields

I use the avada theme with the Fusion Builder. Now I want to create some global templates for the posts and fill the content with ACF.

Does it make a difference for the performance if I write the text directly into the pagebuilder or if I insert the text via ACF shortcode into the pagebuilder? 
There will be around 10-15 Advanced Custom Fields per template which have together around 1500 words and 4 images.

Comment: It mostly depends on whether you'll have caching enabled. If you will, then the ACF shortcode won't impact performance much, only the first rendering until it's cached. If you don't have caching, then yes, using an ACF shortcode does add extra processing time, but that may be negligible. To really explore performance you should build the page a few different ways and benchmark to find out what works best on your particular server.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tested it and it had no impact on the performance.